# How to insert an iframe with javascript to play a youtube video from website, using youtubes data api v3

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-data-api

I am making a youtube clone app, i used youtube data api v3, and trying to get videos on my website and play them. But I only got the thumbnails, I need to get iframe to play the video. How can i do it? Here is the code I am currently using

```
function keyWordsearch(){
    gapi.client.setApiKey('MY-API-KEY');
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function(){
            makeRequest();
    });
}
function makeRequest(){
    var q = $('#query').val();
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            q: q,
            part: 'snippet', 
            maxResults: 10
    });
    request.execute(function(response)  {                                                                                    
            $('#results').empty()
            var srchItems = response.result.items;                      
            $.each(srchItems, function(index, item){
            vidTitle = item.snippet.title;  
            vidThumburl =  item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;                 
            vidThumbimg = '<pre><img id="thumb" src="'+vidThumburl+'" alt="No  Image  Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"></pre>';

            $('#results').append('<pre>' + vidTitle + vidThumbimg +   '</pre>');                      
    })  
  })  
}
```

and HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="buttons">
    <label> <input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/><button id="search-button"    onclick="keyWordsearch()">Search</button></label>    
    <div id="container">
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <ul id="results"></ul>

    </div>        
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady">   </script>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you aware of the official embedding code ? You can find it out below a YouTube video by clicking on Share then click on Embed.

Comment: No there is a search label, i can type there example cats and it will show all youtube thumbnails about cats. Its basically a search engine for youtube. But it shows only thumbnails, i want to get iframes instead of images

Comment: I still don't understand why just changing `VIDEO_ID`, with the video id you got from the search query,  from the [YouTube official embedding code](https://pastebin.com/raw/nNq49FMA) doesn't fit your needs ?